# To shift/readjust something in German

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-german, german-to-english

I am having a hard time with standard English-German dictionaries with figuring out "to shift something" and "to adjust/readjust something" in specific contexts.

Let me give some examples, and what I *think* is the correct translation:

1. The cat shifted the vase on the table. I now need to readjust it.

   > Die Katze hat die Vase auf dem Tisch umgestellt. Ich muss es jetzt richtig stellen.
2. In order to shift the defense forward, the coach readjusted the players around on the field.

   > Um die Verteidigung nach vorne zu verschieben, hatte der Trainer die Spielern auf dem Feld umgestellt.
3. I need to shift my chair (slightly move it to a new location), and readjust it (make it higher/lower).

   > Ich muss meinen Stuhl umstellen, und es einstellen.

As you can see, going from sentences 1, 2, and 3, my translations of "umstellen" go from *shift* to *readjust* and then back to *shift*, and so I'm not sure I really have a good grasp of "shift/adjust/readjust" in German.

Answer (score 1):

*The cat shifted the vase on the table. I now need to readjust it.*

> Die Katze hat die Vase auf dem Tisch **verschoben**. Ich muss sie nun **wieder richtig hinstellen**.

*Verschieben* means changing a position. It's often used instead of *schieben*, which means pushing mainly. Readjust in this case can also be translated as *zurückstellen* or *neu aufstellen*, but in this case *wieder richtig hinstellen* is much more idiomatic.

---

*In order to shift the defense forward, the coach readjusted the players around on the field.*

> Um die Verteidigung**slinie** nach vorne zu verschieben **stellte** der Trainer die Spieler auf dem Feld **um**.

If you write *die Verteidigung* in German, you mean the defense players. But I think you mean the coach readjusted the whole team. You got it right with *umstellen*, but you should stick to *Präteritum* or *Perfekt*, because there isn't a dependend clause but an adverbial phrase.

---

*I need to shift my chair, and readjust it.*

> Ich muss meinen Stuhl umstellen, und (ihn) neu/anders einstellen.

You got that almost right, same *umstellen* as before. Please note you had to use the masculine pronoun if you want to use it at all.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer. Now, I see where I am most confused. You shift the defensive line with "verschieben", but my chair with "umstellen". Is there are good way to understand this difference?

Comment: *Verschieben* is a physical action, while *umstellen* means changing the place or manner. It depends on what you want to express.

Comment: But, "Ich muss meinen Stuhl umstellen" is also a physical action, I am essentially moving the chair, right?

Comment: Consider *Sie müssen ihr Auto umstellen.* vs. *Sie müssen ihr Auto verschieben.* – No, you don't *verschieben* a car, at least not if it's not broken. *Verschieben* is still a kind of *schieben*.

Comment: So, Sie müssen ihr Auto umstellen would be, "you need to re-position your car"=move somewhere else? I apologize for the annoying questions, and thank you for your patience.

Comment: Yes. *Umstellen* just means changing the position or manner, but it doesn't say how.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand now. Just to make sure:

1. Ich habe einige der Bilder an der Wand umgestellt. ( Ich habe sie irgendwie an einen neuen Platz bewegt).

2. Ich habe die Couch ein Stück weg von dem Fernseher verschoben. (Deutet an, dass ich gedrängt habe)

Comment: 2. is correct, but in 1. one would use *umhängen*, not *umstellen* because pictures are usually hanging on a wall, not standing.

Comment: @Mark: *umstellen* is generally -- but not always -- used for things that can be put, "upright", i.e. are in some kind of standing position. If things are hanging, you use *umhängen*. If they are sitting, you can use *umsetzen*, and so on. But you'll have to learn, or get a feeling for when which of these words is used for making a change.

Comment: For me, “umstellen” implies an intentional act, which doesn't fit the cat example (that is, “Die Katze hat die Vase umgestellt” in my ears doesn't just sound less specific, it sounds wrong)

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I think I understand this in terms of physical things. What about more abstract things that still "stehen". For example, "Can we change the sentence around so that it reads better"="...den Satz umstellen...." ? Ändern, "wie der Satz steht"?